# problem with link-time optimization in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm, llvm-gcc

Should I turn on "Generate Debug Symbols" in Xcode for release configuration? When it and "Link Time Optimization" are turned on Xcode show warning:

`GenerateDSYMFile build/Release/cocoa_tutorial5.app.dSYM build/Release/cocoa_tutorial5.app/Contents/MacOS/cocoa_tutorial5
cd /Users/ariel/Documents/spacesimulator.net/cocoa_tutorial5
/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/ariel/Documents/spacesimulator.net/cocoa_tutorial5/build/Release/cocoa_tutorial5.app/Contents/MacOS/cocoa_tutorial5 -o /Users/ariel/Documents/spacesimulator.net/cocoa_tutorial5/build/Release/cocoa_tutorial5.app.dSYM`

warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64) 
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch i386)
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch ppc7400)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Link time optimization and debug information do not currently work together (as of Xcode 3.2, the debug symbols are stripped before they even reach the final executable) in LLVM.</strike>

## UPDATED

Link time optimization and debug information (DWARF or DWARF with dSYM files) work together in Xcode 5 or later.

Comment: Thank you! It means "Generate Debug Symbols" can be turned off to eliminate warning?

Comment: Right, generating debug symbols isn't currently going to be worth doing in a Link Time Optimization build.